# Is it possible to customize User Agent parameter when using ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code fetches the HTML source of `http://www.foo-example-site.com/(index.html)`

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://www.foo-example-site.com', success: function(data) {
    alert(data); 
    } 
});
```

However, the website changes the content of HTML source depending on User Agent.
If I want to switch User Agent to this below only when using ajax request, how can I fix my code?

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is part of the HTTP protocol. You can change it in the browser, but not in an AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any trick to let user's browser to grab external HTML source with customized User Agent params?

Comment: You need to write a browser plug-in to do that.

Comment: It seems too much work:( what if I use PHP or RUBY? Is it feasible?

Comment: You can do that using CURL on the server, but not on the browser.